# Python Pandas query function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
for state in sample_states:
    state_df = df.query("Province_State == state").sum()
```

How can assign values to "state" just so the computer can read what I am referring to when I am going through a list called "sample_states"?

Comment: Most likely you should not even use `query` here. Try `df.groupby("Province_State").sum()`.

Comment: I agree with @DYZ here. You probably don't need to loop through anything.

Comment: @Sean FYI: Thoroughly answering questions is time-consuming. If your question is solved, say thank you by accepting the solution that is best for your needs. The accept check is below the up/down arrow at the top left of the answer. A new solution can be accepted if a better one shows up. You may also vote on the quality/helpfulness of an answer, with the up or down arrow, if you have a 15+ reputation. Leave a comment if a solution doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use '@', per [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
for state in sample_states:
    state_df = df.query("Province_State == @state").sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using fstring (Python 3.6+):

```
for state in sample_states:
    state_df = df.query(f"Province_State == {state}").sum()
```

The syntax for fstring is fairly simple, just add `f` before any string, and then just add `{...}` over any variable.

Or just use the old "String formatter" (Python 2.6+ -> but introduced since python 3):

```
for state in sample_states:
    state_df = df.query(f"Province_State == {}".format(state)).sum()
```